# logback value from web.xml in file appender

Tags: java, glassfish, logback

I am developing Java web application for Glassfish server. I have problem with setting path for File appender. I would like to use variable which is defined in web.xml.

Web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>app.myApp-client.home</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Logback.xml (in src/main/resurces)

```
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">        
    <file>${app.myApp-client.home}/WEB-INF/app-log/client.log</file>        
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

After deploy my application on Glassfish log file with name

> /app.myApp-client.home_IS_UNDEFINED/WEB-INF/app-log/client.log

is created. Why parameter app.myApp-client.home is undefined? Is there any better option for put application path to file appender?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to set variables to values [obtained via JNDI](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#insertFromJNDI). In your case, you would write:

```
  <insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:comp/env/webAppRootKey" as="webAppRootKey" />

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">        
    <file>${webAppRootKey}/WEB-INF/app-log/client.log</file>        
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%date %level [%file:%line] %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
```

The above should work nicely. In addition, you might also find it useful to [set a default value](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#defaultValuesForVariables) for `${webAppRootKey}`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the value instead of the param name...

Try it like this:

```
<file>${webAppRootKey}/WEB-INF/app-log/client.log</file>
```

But I guess this will give you `/app.myApp-client.home/WEB-INF/app-log/client.log` and that is also not what you expected? :)

Comment: You are right. I would like to put path of my application on server (for example /home/glassfish/domains/domain1/j2ee-modules/MyApplication on something else) - is there any constant/variable for it?

Comment: What about `${application.home}` as in the [play logging docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger)

Answer (score 0):

There is some info about configuring logback via JNDI here: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/loggingSeparation.html

Also there is discussion of ways to do it here: http://logback.10977.n7.nabble.com/Externalized-Logback-configuration-for-web-applications-td3629.html