# logback value from web.xml

Tags: java, spring, logback, web.xml

I'm trying to take a value from spring profile set in web.xml. I've already encountered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274692/logback-value-from-web-xml-in-file-appender) that solves my problem but the implementation of the solution to the problem does not seem to be working. That's are my source code:

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>local-jboss</param-value>
</context-param>
```

logback.xml:

```
<insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:comp/env/spring.profiles.default" as="spring.profiles.default" />

<appender name="STASH" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>x.x.x.x:yyyy</destination>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <mdc /> <!-- MDC variables on the Thread will be written as JSON fields -->
            <context /> <!-- Outputs entries from logback's context -->
            <version /> <!-- Logstash json format version, the @version field in the output -->
            <logLevel />
            <loggerName />
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                {
                    "APP": "MyApp",
                    "PROFILE": "${spring.profiles.default}"
                }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
            <threadName />
            <message />
            <logstashMarkers /> <!-- Useful so we can add extra information for specific log lines as Markers -->
            <arguments /> <!-- or through StructuredArguments -->
            <stackTrace />
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Does anyone know how I get the value from my web.xml and put in logback.xml?

Answer (score 0):

**1st Solution :**

If you are on spring 3.1+ then those context params will available as env variable and in logback you can easily refer them like below :

```
<springProperty scope="context" name="fluentHost" source="myapp.fluentd.host"
        defaultValue="localhost"/>
```

`source` is the name of your key. Further [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#_environment_properties).

**2nd Solution :**
You can use this as well where we will define context-param as spring property then refer the same in logback as 1st solution above.

```
@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    private ServletContext servletContext;
    public static void main(String[] args){SpringApplication.run(DemoApp.class,args);}
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        builder = builder.properties("test.property:" + servletContext.getInitParameter("test.property"));
        return builder.sources(DemoApp.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.